# Create BaseFragment and extend this Fragment in ChildFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I don't know whether this is repeated question or not, But I didn't found any solution.

The problem is, there is a screen which has similar views in all the screens, that screens are in fragment.

So, I want to create a base fragment and want to extend this base fragment in all child fragments.

I found on google, for demo examples, But I didn't find any solution.

I don't know from where to start.

Please help me.

I found this links but it is not much clear:

1. [Fragments inheritance Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26049114/fragments-inheritance-android)
2. [When do I need a base activity and base fragment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32552592/when-do-i-need-a-base-activity-and-base-fragment)

BaseFragment.java

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

  public BaseFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
  }

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_base, container, false);
  }
}
```

ChildFragment.Java

```
public class ChildFragment extends BaseFragment{

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);
  }
}
```

Now, there is a TextView in fragment_child layout. that is displayed when I run the app,
but there are two other views in fragment_base, that is not showing...

[image]

Comment: I see what you want, but I don't see what is your problem. What is the problem?

Comment: I am new to android, and this is the first time i am working with fragment. so i don't know exactly how to start and where to start.

Comment: if there is any demo example for using of base fragment, then it would be helpful

Comment: There is nothing special about a Fragment comparing to any other base class. Just do whatever is common for all classes in your base class, and whatever is specific - in child classes.

Comment: please see my edited question...

Comment: in your code you just ignore whatever is done by your base class.

Comment: Are you trying to declare views in BaseFragment's XML and then use them in your child Fragments?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**ABSTRACT CLASS APPROACH ?**

I understand what you are trying to do (inheritance) here. But as pointed out by @hobokent, just by inheriting the BaseClass will not include your childView layout on top of BaseClass Layout.
There are many ways to conquer this problem

Let's look into this solution.

- Create an abstract class which will extend the Fragment Class (This
  will be BaseClass).
- Make an abstract method which will return a layout.
- Provide implementation for your abstract method in the ChildClass.

Here is the code snippet.

> BaseClass

```
public abstract class BasicFragment extends Fragment {

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  }

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanseState)
   {
      View view = provideYourFragmentView(inflater,parent,savedInstanseState);
      return view;
   }

   public abstract View provideYourFragmentView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState);

}
```

> ChildClass

```
public class ImageFragment extends BasicFragment{

  @Override
  public View provideYourFragmentView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.image_fragment,parent,false);

    //Now specific components here (you can initialize Buttons etc)

    return view;
   }


}
```

For your specific requirement, if you want the same layout to appear in child class layout. You can make a method which will return a layout and maybe in your child layout you make a placeholder for BaseClass Layout and add the BaseClass layout in childLayout using child.add(base_layout).
Again it is just another design solution.
You can also put a common layout in Activity layout and Add fragment in Activity placeholder for the fragment. 
There are so many possible solutions.

I don't have any code specific to your requirement but here is the example where I have implemented this approach for TabLayout, where each tab is a different Fragment with a different layout.
[Github full code sample](https://github.com/rohitksingh/TabLayout/tree/master/TabLayout/app/src/main/java/com/googletabs/rohksin/tablayout/Fragments).

Comment: I also worked out something like that below but kept ir simplier. Dont know if my way is the solution but used in my Android project and that worked well..

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented this structure where you can have your BaseFragment layout appear in your ChildFragment layout. Basically, I've used ViewStub to implement the solution. VewStub is kinda placeholder layout. It will be created when `xml` is loaded and then you can replace the [ViewStub](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub) with designated view hierarchy. I'm gonna use self-explanatory variable names to avoid additional explanation :). You can check out the [sample project](https://github.com/mecoFarid/FragmentLayoutInheritance) on GitHub.

> fragment_core.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/child_fragment_will_be_displayed_here"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
    </ViewStub>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/core_fragment_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/child_fragment_content_holder"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

> FragmentCore.class

```
   public abstract class FragmentCore extends Fragment {

    public FragmentCore() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

     protected TextView mTextViewInCoreActivity;

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                              Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View coreFragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_core, container, false);
         mTextViewInCoreActivity = coreFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.core_fragment_text_view);
         loadLayoutFromResIdToViewStub(coreFragmentView, container);
         return coreFragmentView;
     }

     public abstract void loadLayoutFromResIdToViewStub(View rootView,ViewGroup container);

 }
```

> fragment_child.xml

```
 <FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/child_fragment_content_holder">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/child_fragment_text_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

> FragmentChild.class

```
    public class FragmentChild extends FragmentCore {


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void loadLayoutFromResIdToViewStub(View coreFragmentView, ViewGroup container){

        setRetainInstance(true);

        if (container != null) {
            container.removeAllViews();
        }

        ViewStub stub = coreFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.child_fragment_will_be_displayed_here);
        stub.setLayoutResource(R.layout.fragment_child);
        stub.inflate();

        TextView childFragmentTextView = coreFragmentView.findViewById(R.id.child_fragment_text_view);

        mTextViewInCoreActivity.setText("Core (Parent) Fragment TextView is accessible");
        childFragmentTextView.setText("Child Fragment TextView is accessible");
    }

}
```

Comment: I think my solution below keeps it clean. It just injects a function in the onCreateView. You need the fragment name for it, so the injector and the name are the abstracts.

Answer (score 1):

Extending the Fragment won't include the views, those views are from which layout you inflate, therefore you won't see the text views from fragment_base in your Child Fragment.

It might benefit you to instead create and use custom views/compound views that you can then reuse in your other fragments.

You can read up on Compound Views here:

https://medium.com/@Sserra90/android-writing-a-compound-view-1eacbf1957fc

Answer (score 0):

BaseFragment extends Fragment class and then your other Fragments extends BaseFragment

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment 

public class AboutFragment extends BaseFragment
```

if you want other layouts in:

```
 View headView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout. - your Fragment layout - , null, false);
```

This is working for me.

Hope it helped.

Comment: BaseFragment should be abstract class.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by including a base layout for each child fragment. Then you need to bind the view in the base fragment for all the base view in the base layout. For the child view layout, you need to bind it in the child fragment.

Here the step:

1. Create the base fragment layout (fragment_base.xml):

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout>

          <!-- Declare your view here -->
          <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
              android:id="@+id/sample_tv"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Sample"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
   ```
2. Create the base fragment

   ```
   public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

     public BaseFragment() {
       // Required empty public constructor
     }

     ...
   }
   ```
3. Create a base method in the base fragment to bind the view. This will be overridden and reuse in your child fragment. Here we use `bindView()` name:

   ```
   public class BaseFragment extends Fragment {

     protected AppCompatTextView mTvSample;

     ...

     protected void bindView(View view) {
       mTvSample = view.findViewById(R.id.sample_tv);
     }
     ...

   }
   ```
4. Create the child layout by reusing the base layout. You can use **include**. It should be something like this (fragment_child.xml):

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <RelativeLayout>

          <include
               layout="@layout/fragment_base"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
          />

          <!-- Child view -->
          <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
              android:id="@+id/child_tv"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Child Sample"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
   ```
5. Now you can create the child fragment by extending the base fragment. You need to remember to use and override the `bindView()`. So, you need to make something like this:

   ```
   public class ChildFragment extends BaseFragment {
     private AppCompatTextView mTvChild;
     public ChildFragment() {
       // Required empty public constructor

     }


     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child, container, false);

       bindView(view);
       return view;
     }

     @Ovverride
     protected void bindView(View view) {
       super.bindView(view); //call base method to bind the base view
       mTvChild = view.findViewById(R.id.child_tv);
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: as u added <include> tag in child_fragment, do i need to make changes like this to every view???

Comment: i had same functionality for those views in all fragment. can i write that functionality at only once and use other views in other fragments?

Comment: That's right. It means that you want to reuse the fragment_base layout in your child.

Comment: Of course, you can create the method for the base functionality as long as it doesn't need a direct access to its child. This is using the same principle in oop.

Comment: plz check the image i added, there are 2 views, cam1 and cam2, these are cameras. This camera views has same functionality in more than 5 fragments. i just need to replace views in bottom.

Comment: You can create the base layout with the cameras. Then reuse the layout in the child fragment.

Comment: how to, just call base fragment and replace the views in bottom view, based on selected fragments. and base fragment camera functionality should remain as it is and should also works on every fragment where i extends it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154125/discussion-between-demo-mail-and---).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
abstract class BaseFragment : Fragment() {

override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container:ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {
    return inflater.inflate(getContentView(), container, false)
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        onViewReady(savedInstanceState, arguments)
    }
// create below 2 methods
    abstract fun getContentView(): Int // this will be used to pass view
    abstract fun onViewReady(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, bundle: Bundle?) // this will be invoked in our fragment when view is ready
}
```

Fragment

```
    class SoundFragment : BaseFragment() {
    override fun getContentView() = R.layout.fragment_sound

    override fun onViewReady(savedInstanceState: Bundle?, bundle: Bundle?) {
       // write your code here...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this simple and clean approach

```
public abstract class BaseFragment extends Fragment { 
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(getLayoutId(), null);

    return root;
}

@LayoutRes
protected abstract int getLayoutId();
}
```

that's it for base fragment

Then for child fragment

```
public class ChildFragment extends BaseFragment {

@Override
protected int getLayoutId() {
    return R.layout.child_fragment;
}

}
```

**Make seprate methods for do your stuffs**

Answer (score 0):

The most simple and clean solution is to keep the onCreateView as it is and inject a function in it. But you need the fragment name for this to work. So two abstracts are needed, an view create injector and a name getter and you end up with a clean and very workable solution. I used it for one Activity with 10 replaceable fragments in it:

```
/**
 * base class for the application
 */
public abstract class AppFragment extends Fragment {

    // use shared view model for exchanging information between fragments.
    SharedViewModel sharedViewModel;

    /**
     * create view
     * @param inflater - inflater creates the view
     * @param container - container with views
     * @param savedInstanceState - for saving state
     * @return - return view
     */
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // call base class first
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        // then create view
        View fragView = inflater.inflate(getFragment(), container, false);

        // get shared view model.
        sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);

        // inject fragment depended code
        createView(fragView);

        // return created view
        return fragView;
    }

    /**
     * get fragment
     */
    protected abstract int getFragment();

    /**
     * inject fragment depended code while creating the view
     */
    protected abstract void createView(View fragView);
```

then use it like this:

```
/**
 * make mot or tp empty
 */
public class EmptyFragment extends AppFragment {

    // parameter from load fragment
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "paramSubject";
    private String paramSubject;

    // empty view
    View emptyView;

    /**
     * factory method for creating new instance of this fragment
     * @param paramSubject - subject from load fragment
     * @return - new instance of this fragment
     */
    public static EmptyFragment newInstance(String paramSubject) {
        EmptyFragment fragment = new EmptyFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, paramSubject);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    /**
     * get param subject from load fragment when creating this fragment
     * @param savedInstanceState - save state data
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null)
            paramSubject = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
    }

    /**
     * set fragment for view
     * @return - return used fragment
     */
    @Override
    protected int getFragment() {
        return R.layout.empty_fragment;
    }

    /**
     * create view
     * @param emptyView - created view by base class
     */
    @Override
    protected void createView(View emptyView) {

        // subject edit
        EditText editTextFrom = emptyView.findViewById(R.id.editTextFrom);
        editTextFrom.setText(paramSubject);

        // set headers
        sharedViewModel.getSubject().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), subject -> {

            // set header
            TextView textViewHeader = emptyView.findViewById(R.id.textViewHeader);
            String headerString = String.format(
                requireActivity().getString(R.string.message_makeempty),
                requireActivity().getString(subject));
            textViewHeader.setText(headerString);

            // subject header
            TextView textViewSubject = emptyView.findViewById(R.id.textViewSubject);
            textViewSubject.setText(subject);

            // only needed when its a tp
            if (subject == R.string.subject_mot) {
                SwitchMaterial switchBIC = emptyView.findViewById(R.id.switchBICCode);
                switchBIC.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            // listener when empty button is pressed
            emptyMessageListener(emptyView, subject);
        });
    }
```